# Name of 3 dots button

Tags: button, ellipses

I am trying to get the official name for the 3 dots horizontal and 3 dots vertical buttons in SharePoint. What I have come up with at the end is **Ellipsis** for the horizontal three dots and **Kabob** or **ant** for the vertical three dots and prefer Kabob. Are these right or are there any official name for these buttons?

Answer (score 6):

Referring [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34755666/7920473), We have many names for each of it. Nothing is official.

[image]

3 horizontal dots - (horizontal) ellipsis, meatballs menu

3 vertical dots - vertical ellipsis, kebab, dango menu

9 dots - bento, waffle menu

3 horizontal lines - hamburger menu

Comment: 3 vertical dots I heard ebay calls it Kabob like kebab i guess

Comment: @SANJAYSIVAKUMAR can you accept it as answer?